# removing Title area section SharePoint

Tags: css, sharepoint

I want to remove the  title area section which is above view all site content not the breadcrumb and move my quick launch next to breadcrumb...having

```
<td class="ms-titlearealeft" id="TitleAreaImageCell" valign="top" nowrap style="width: 1px; border-style: none; height: 1px;" height="1px"><div style="height:100%" class="ms-titleareaframe"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server"/></div></td>
```

this blank space above quick launch shows for all the pages.But when I am removing this my breadcrumb is getting towards left section which I don't want..Any idea how to remove this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a panel in side the master page 
Cut the `<tr>` section of the place holder witch handles the title  paste it inside the panel.

```
<asp:Panel visible="false" runat="server">
<table><tr><td>hiding placeholders</td></tr></table>

<tr>
    <td class="ms-titlearealeft" id="TitleAreaImageCell" valign="middle" nowrap>
    <div style="height:100%" class="ms-titleareaframe">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </td>
</asp:Panel>
```

make sure visiblity of your panel is hidden.
now you can get your quick launch next to bread crumb
Like this way you can hide othe place holders

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing the master page? Why don't you just place a blank image there or something?

Comment: if i will do that too...bt still there wud be an empty space over there...or blank image ...I want that my quicklaunch should be touching my top navigation nd there would not be any space in between for image or sth...

Comment: then you need to change the layout of the masterpage accordingly, it's like editing any HTML page